OpenXML Library Causes Performance Issues for Word Documents
I use OpenXML Library to read, open, change and save Microsoft Word documents with .Net 6.0  application. No performance issues occur when creating small or medium sized Word documents which can be up to about 400-500 pages. But after 600 pages, just opening a Word document using Microsoft Word is a huge problem. For example I opened a Word document whose page size is about 1200 pages, and updating table of contents and changing documents to a PDF lasted almost 2 hours. This is not acceptable in any way, so I need a solution.
The Word document I used has a fixed template so I can't create it from sctract. Firstly, I retrieve Word document which I have created the template beforehand and open it. To prevent adding any Word item and ruin Word document by it, I retrieve all business-nodes with var businessNodeX = parentElement.ChildElements[15].CloneNode(true) command and I use these nodes again and again by copy-cloning them. After every clone and update node command, I insert these cloned-nodes to the original document and this goes on for thousands of records.
I tried changing my library to Xceed Word or other libraries but changing hundrends of code line of business-logic is also not seemed logical so I need a performance-wise solutions.
Here is my C# code below:
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
}

using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
{
    document.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
    var body = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

    var parentElement = body.ChildElements[0];
    var businessNode1 = parentElement.ChildElements[13].CloneNode(true);
    var businessNode2 = parentElement.ChildElements[14].CloneNode(true);
    var businessNodeX = parentElement.ChildElements[15].CloneNode(true);
    //other nodes ...
    var nodeToInsertBefore = parentElement.ChildElements[9];

    //business logic
    //there are tens of thousand of records so even inserting these nodes last 5-10 minutes in application
    parentElement.InsertBefore(businessNode1.CloneNode(true), nodeToInsertBefore);
    parentElement.InsertBefore(businessNode2.CloneNode(true), nodeToInsertBefore);
    parentElement.InsertBefore(businessNodeX.CloneNode(true), nodeToInsertBefore);
}


Have you used a profiler to see where time is being spent?

I didn't. Because while creating a Word document is one of the problems, my actual problem is opening the Word document by Microsoft Word takes to much time.

But I will also check the code with a profiler, thanks for the suggestion @AKX

The Word document I used has a fixed template: Was the template created in Word or with some other application? If the issue is when opening with Word. Follow the process described here to ensure that the format that exists when one creates the document strictly using Word matches that which exists after you've modified it using OpenXML (format used in this context means the XML). Most likely the issue is with your modifications.

The word document was created in Microsoft Word. My first comment could be misleading because opening 400 paged Word document is not problem but opening 1000+ paged document is, because just opening it takes too much times which is not acceptable.

opening 400 paged Word document is not problem but opening 1000+ paged document is:  I would expect a 1000 page document to take some time to open. If you create a 1000 page document using Word (without using your application), does it take a similar amount of time to open? If you open the same 1000 page document 10 times, rebooting your computer before you open the document each time, what is the average amount of time that it takes? What is the shortest amount of time? The longest? Are you using the 32-bit version of Word or 64-bit version?
